# C# console Webclient does not return data but browser does

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, console-application, webclient

I am trying to download a PDF from a URL using a Windows console application. I am using the below code:

```
 using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
         webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");    
                byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(url);    
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Files\hello.pdf", data);
 }
```

If I copy and paste the same url in the above code in the browser/postman, I get the file however, when I try the same in the C# console application, I get some other HTML response. I intercepted the request/response using Fiddler and the only difference I could see is that when the request is fired through browser/postman, I see that some extra cookies are added to the request which are specific to the application we are working on. I am confused as to how come the browser/postman can add cookies specific to the application.

I tried clearing all the cookies and tried it again from the browser, but Fiddler shows the cookies in the request. Any clues as to what is going on?

Comment: Frequently cookies used for authentication of some sort... It is up to you to come up with hacks to either obtain them (i.e. by requesting page first/faking sign-in) or steal from browser... Generally sites are not tested to work correctly when someone tries to scrape them, and often explicitly setup to deter such behavior by checking cookies/referrer/hidden auto-generated fields and the like.

Answer (score -1):

check this code

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = @"Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 54.0.2840.99 Safari / 537.36";

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    // write
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need those bytes? Download and save with one line:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf", "C:\\book.pdf");
}
```

Comment: tried that, but it gives the same result as of those bytes

Comment: as you can see provided samle downloads a file. if this is not the case give additional details, like you URL.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve